# Where can I find the version numbers of gems with the Ruby version it is compatible with?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

The question says it all.

For example, I have a server with ruby 1.8.6 installed. And when I try `sudo gem install roo`, it gives an error `nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7`. So, I want to install an older version of `roo` which is compatible with `Ruby 1.8.6`. But I dont know where to search. I know of `RubyForge` but it also does not say about the compatible versions of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach would be to get a git clone, search for where it specifies what Ruby version it's after, and use `git blame` or even the git pickaxe to determine the last version that didn't have that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. Turns out, nokogiri 1.5 deprecates 1.8.6 support.

The last Nokogiri version to support 1.8.6 is version 1.4.4

Source: [The Nokogiri change notes](http://nokogiri.org/CHANGELOG_rdoc.html)